# extract selected item from a list in jps

Tags: mysql

I have a list in `jsp` which is populated with data from a `MySQL` table:

`<p class="news"> 
        <%  java.sql.Connection c=MyConnection.connect();
            java.util.List<Employee> lista=MyConnection.getEmployeeList();
                for(Employee emp: lista)
            {%>
                <ul>
                 <li> <a href="showEmployeeActivity.jsp"><%=emp.getName() %></a></li>
                </ul>
             <%}%>
      </p>
      </div>`

When I click on an item from my html list opens another jsp file  showEmployeeActivity.jsp.
  In showEmployeeActivity.jsp I want to show a list with all activities of my selected employee :

`<p class="news"> 
        <%  java.sql.Connection c=MyConnection.connect();
            java.util.List<Activity>list2=MyConnection.getEmployeeActivity(String name);
                for(Activity act: list2)
            {%>
                <ul>
                 <li> <a href="showEmployeeActivity.jsp"><%=act.toString() %></a></li>
                </ul>
             <%}%>
      </p>
      </div>`

Method getEmployeeActivity(String name) contain a select from table "activity" where employee's name is the one I clicked in first jsp file.

I don't know how to return clicked item from first jsp and use it in second jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Add onclick method and use ajax to forward it to the next page:

```
<a href="showEmployeeActivity.jsp" onclick="getEmpName(this.name)"><%=emp.getName() %></a>

//Script ajax


   var aj;
    function getEmpName(EmpName){
    //Do ajax and redirect it to your next page. You will get Empname here
    try {
                aj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e) {
                aj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
                   aj.onreadystatechange = ajaxres;
            aj.open("get", "secondpage.jsp" + EmpName, true); // here you are passing EmpName to second page, What ever you need is to be created there
            aj.send();
    }
function ajaxres(){
if (aj.readyState == 4) {
                var restxt = aj.responseText;//This is your response
        }
}
```

Hope it may solve your issue!!

Comment: thank you, but i'm a beginner and  i never used ajax, can you give me more details , please. how this function should look like and how can I use it in second jsp

Comment: @POPESCUG answer updated. I am using simple javascript for ajax there  because you are new. There is alternative jquery is available. Just check it!!